# jQueryMobile listview with filter reveal, show items on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview created with jqueryMobile using the data-filter reveal feature. This feature hides the list elements and shows those matching the entered characters as you type. My data source is local (meaning the list is statically populated).

What I would like to do is to show all items without the need to enter any characters, but when the list itself gets the focus (and hide them when it's lost).

I know I could just jQuery all elements and do the show/hiding myself but I was wondering whether there was an out-of-the box solution available that I don't know of.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery mobile 1.3.2 with jquery 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the box solution, however, you can do the following.

When `input` is *focused*, set `.listview( "option", "filterReveal", true );` and hide all list view items manually by adding `ui-screen-hidden` jQM class. When *blurred*, reverse the previous action.

**Note**: *filterReveal* is deprecated in jQM 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0.

```
var list = $("#list");

$("input").on("focus", function () {
    $(this).val("");
    list.listview("option", "filterReveal", false);
    list.children().removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    list.listview("refresh");
}).on("keydown", function () {
    list.listview("option", "filterReveal", true);
    list.children().addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    list.listview("refresh");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5zcB8/)**

Comment: This is not exactly what I asked, what I would like is for the input to hide the list but show it immediately as it gains focus, instead of just when typing the first character. But I guess I can get it out of your example. Thanks.

Comment: @kelmer this hides elements once focused. initially, you want list items hidden and on focus, show them? edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5zcB8/