# How to toggle the search bar on JQuery ListView?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to dynamically change the data-filter attribute of a ListView I am using in JQuery mobile. Here is the code I am using:

```
var $listview = $('#myList');
console.log( $listview.attr('data-filter'));
$listview.attr('data-filter',
   $listview.attr('data-filter')=='false' ? 'true' : 'false'
);
console.log( $listview.attr('data-filter'));
$('#my_view').trigger( "create");
```

When this code runs I can see in the console that the data-filter attribute changes between true and false in my logs.

However the search bar never appears on screen, I have tried refreshing the listview, refreshing the page and finally tried using the create on the page as you can see in the code.

However nothing works, how can I get the search bar to show up on the screen after setting the data-filter to true?

EDIT: To clarify I want the search bar to toggle, not for the ListView to toggle

Comment: which jQM version are you using? check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001885/jquerymobile-listview-with-filter-reveal-show-items-on-click/21002863#21002863

Comment: I am using 1.3.2, the link seems to be the opposite to what I want, I want the search to appear and disappear, not the list?

Comment: its not possible in 1.3.2. the only way is to create it with listview and then hide/show it. Or keep a hidden non-enhanced clone, post it when you need it.

Comment: Is it possible in later versions?

Comment: it's possible in jQM 1.4

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Q65cb/ jQM 1.4 use _filterable_ widget. its a new feature that can be used on any elements.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure if thats what I want? It still appears to be showing/hiding the listview rather than the search bar? I want to show a list view with no search bar then press a button to show the search bar and then press the button again to hide it.

Comment: if this is what you want, then you can do it in jQM 1.3.2 as I said before, create listvie with filter option true and then hide it. This demo is for jQM 1.4 http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Q65cb/

Comment: How do I hide the filter option from Javascript in 1.3.2 though, do you know of any examples?

Comment: `$("ul").prev("form").hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

remove like this..

```
$("#id").removeAttr("data-filter");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one on the page, just use: `$(".ui-filterable").toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Just Posting from comments: In case it helps someone.

- Use the following to hide search bars of all ul in the page:

  ```
  $("ul").prev("form").hide();
  ```
- Use the following to hide search bars of particular ul in the page:

  ```
  $(".myListClass").prev("form").hide();
  $("#myListID").prev("form").hide();
  ```